# vscode api for file explorer

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am onto writing a VSCode extension and need to create files / remove files based in a folder / subfolder selected by the user.

Is there a way to find selected folder from the explorer tree through visual studio code api? One can track the opened file through active text editor or `onDidOpenTextDocument()`. I am interested in finding if user has selected a folder and if so the path to selected folder.

For example: `workspace.rootPath` provides a root of the opened project. Similarly, how do I identify which subfolder is selected by the user (if any).

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 10):

I finally figured it out,  I've been looking for a while and found that the documentation states that :

> Note: When a command is invoked from a (context) menu, VS Code tries to infer the currently selected resource and passes that as a parameter when invoking the command. For instance, a menu item inside the Explorer is passed the URI of the selected resource and a menu item inside an editor is passed the URI of the document.
>   [vscode extension contribution points](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/extension-points)

That let me to this question/bug on github [Get selected file folder](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3553), which in turn led me to the github repo of 
[stef-levesque/vscode-hexdump](https://github.com/stef-levesque/vscode-hexdump/blob/master/src/extension.ts) from which I got the following:

```
let disposable = Commands.registerCommand('extension.superExtension', async (fileUri) => {
    console.log(fileUri);
})
```

Note: when the context menu is used in the editor this will be empty.

Comment: thanks! I have tested this and it functions correctly.

Comment: How to get the path a selected folder or file, without use a contextual menu ?